FilledPolarCurve: Area and Integrate give different values
Version 14.1 introduces FilledPolarCurve as a new way to make regions.
In some cases, Area and integrating 1 over the region give different values for the region's area. Is this a bug?
Example:
r = FilledPolarCurve[Cos[3 \[Theta]], \[Theta]];
{Area[r], Integrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] r]}

gives {Pi/2, Pi/4}. So Area is twice as large as the integral.
The parametric version of this region
rp = RegionConvert[r, "Parametric"]

gives the same result: {Pi/2, Pi/4}
However, the implicit version of the region
ri = RegionConvert[r, "Implicit"]

gives the same value for Area and Integrate, both equal to Pi/4.
And discretizing the region
rd = DiscretizeRegion[r];
{Area[rd], Integrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] rd]}

gives the same numerical value {0.780069, 0.780069} close to Pi/4.

FilledPolarCurve is in my opinion very badly documented and quite useless. If you look at the InputForm of the region, you will see that the range of $\theta$ is $[0, 2\pi]$, even though your curve has a period $\pi$. FilledPolarCurve[Cos[3 θ], θ] // InputForm gives Region[ParametricRegion[{{Cos[θ]*Cos[3*θ]*\[FormalR], Cos[3*θ]*\[FormalR]*Sin[θ]}, 0 <= \[FormalR] <= 1 && 0 <= θ <= 2*Pi}, {\[FormalR], θ}]]

Classic calc student error. @Domen seems to blame Mathematica. As a teacher, I always felt it was the student's fault. Report it to WRI and let the developers sort out which view is to be considered right. Oddly, the correct domain is calculated for FilledPolarCurve[Cos[5/2 \[Theta]], \[Theta]], but the area is wrong, which should be $2$ (assuming even-odd filling).

Thanks for the feedback. Let's see what WRI says about this. At the very least, it should. be a 'possible issue' in the documentation, along with a clearer definition of what FilledPolarCurve does to give a set of points in the plane.
